# Avoid type variable infered as unknown for manually curried functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, type-inference, currying

I usually curry my function manually through arrow syntax. There seems to be an issue with type inference as soon as generic type parameters come into play:

```
type Const<A, B> = { const: A };

const Const = <A, B>(x: A): Const<A, B> => ({ const: x });

const map = <F, A, B>(f: (_: A) => B) => (tx: Const<F, B>) => tx;

const inc = (x: number) => x + 1;

const foo = map(inc) (Const("foo")); // Const<unknown, number> instead of <string, number>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7ADwEEA0UBCA+KAXigG8oBjRFALinSgF8BuAWACh3LlhYqfiM2fAAoAHrXQBKWvG6DcBQgWFkuNKKMaTWHNmp4BbAIZgiUVAH1sWBcIBmtYRYmSiBHK6VRhwcbzlWCp4EvjqcfFAAlgjkZmK0CACuBgBGEABOwRpQANRQAIxhehF2cHBmxmDC0eSuwrIowgBEpXBNktpAA)

When I uncurry `map` everything works as expected. How can I keep my functions curried without losing type inference?

Comment: What's the point of the `B` type variable in `type Const<A, B> = { const: A };`?

Comment: You certainly know phantom types. I am not an expert but one use case is to get a proper return type of a value constructor, even if you don't have enough data at that point (in the given example the type constructor is specialzed to `Const<string, number>`). Sometimes there is no data at all (`Nil`/`List<A>`). I think `Const` is just a variation of `Either` without the `Right` value constructor. There are certainly a couple of scenarios where it offers the necessary extra bit of polymorphism.

Comment: If you're exploring other type-safe languages that compile to JS, I highly recommend looking at OCaml/ReasonML

Comment: @Thankyou Hm, I tend to stick with the language of the common people and make the best of it.. However, Ocaml seems to be a lovely language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move type parameters to the function where they are actually used as parameters.

In this case `F` has no inference site in the `map`, it is only used in the return type (inferring from called return type, is not something TS does, it does infer from return type in other scenarios but not this). Moving the type parameter to the function returned by `map` lets the second call infer `F` and produces the expected type.

```
type Const<A, B> = { const: A };

const Const = <A, B>(x: A): Const<A, B> => ({ const: x });

const map = <A, B>(f: (_: A) => B) => <F>(tx: Const<F, B>) => tx;

const inc = (x: number) => x + 1;

const foo = map(inc) (Const("foo"));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7ADwEEA0UBCA+KAXigG8oBjRFALinSgF8BuAKBcuWFiq+I23wAKAB610ASlrxO-XAUIFBZDjSjDG41ux5QAtgEMwRKLKEAzWoID6Y8UQI47CkwDE8g4KO4yXAvE4JPLRUuAEsEcmMRWgQAV10AIwgAJwC1KABqKABGYJ0zODhjAzBBcPI7QWkUQQAiArha8U0oIA)

Comment: Um, that was trivial. Feels odd to be a rookie again. Thanks!